# Unity Xcode build AdBannerViewController.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to build some existing Unity 4.6 projects in Unity 5 and Xcode 6.1.1 Unity build is successful. However when building the file in Xcode 6.1.1 I am getting the error `AdBannerViewController.h file not found`. The error is occurring in 
`Unity-iPhone/Libraries/Scripts/Front/NativeUIBinding.m`. It is being imported and referenced in that file.

These appear to be unity developed files with no relevance to the app. Any idea why this header file would be missing? I searched the project but cannot find it and its a very simple two scene app that doesn't use ads.

Comment: Are you creating a new xcode project when you build, or do you append to an existing one?

Comment: I have tried both replacing and deleting the folder and creating a new one, same issue both times.